# Ошибка при использовании idiv

Tags: ассемблер

Выскакивает ошибка при idiv bx Двойное слово делю на слово, не знаю почему выскакивает divide by zero. При этом когда я делю на bl оно делит, но не правильно, ответ должен выходить FF..66BB - через калькулятор считал.

```
    .model small
    .stack 100h
    .data
a   db  50
b   db  60  
c   db  20
d   db  30
e   db  40
f   dw  ?
    .code
    .486    
    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax
    mov bl,c
    shl bl,1
    mov     al,d
    imul    al
    xchg    ax,bx
    cbw
    sub ax,bx
    xchg    ax,bx
    xor cx,0
    mov cl,a
    mov al,b
    imul    al
    add ax,cx
    imul    bx
    xchg    bx,ax
    mov al,e
    cbw
    add al,al
    xchg    bx,ax
    xchg    ax,dx
    shl eax,16
    mov ax,dx
    idiv    bx      ;dx:ax/bx gde dx:ax dvoinoe slovo a bx slovo
    ;mov    f,
    mov ax,4c00h
    int 21h
    end
```

Comment: а ещё научите правильно вставлять код, ибо кавычки поставил, а оно не работает(((

Comment: Вставляете код, выделяете его и нажимаете на фигурные скобки в меню форматирования.

Comment: хотя странно конечно, судя по всему в bl в это время должно быть 80 ... надо под отладчиком все таки по шагам посмотреть

Comment: и при делении ошибка может возникать так же в случае если частное не влезает в целевой регистр (в ax). так как в bx явно не ноль, можно предположить, что в dx:ax слишком большое значение